# How to calculate the sum for parents in postgresql if the values ​only for the most recent children are known, and the nesting size is unknown?

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a table with four columns: id, p_id, power, ord. Each parent has 5 children, but power is known only when ord = 0. It is required to calculate the power of all, provided that for the parent it is equal to the sum of its values ​​in the children. with ord = 1,2,... power = 0. There are approximately 500,000 values ​​in the table.

```
id     p_id     power   ord
0   390625  -15 0
1   390625  62  0
2   390625  23  0
3   390625  -71 0
4   390625  -18 0
5   390626  95  0
6   390626  -66 0
7   390626  -94 0
8   390626  -57 0
9   390626  97  0
10  390627  97  0
...
488280  -1  0   8

with recursive Tree(id, p_id, pow, ord, Ch ) as (
    select id, p_id, pow, ord,id
    from Tab1
    where id = 0
    union distinct
    select Tab1.id, Tab1.p_id, case when tab1.ord = 0 then tab1.pow else tree.pow end as pow, Tab1.ord,
             case when tab1.ord = 0 then tab1.id else tree.Ch end as Ch
    from Tab1
    inner join Tree
    on Tab1.id = Tree.p_id or Tab1.id  = Tree.Ch + 1)
select *
from tree
limit 100
```

This recursive query displays for each row the occurrence of each child with ord = 0, but there are a lot of them, since for large ords pow(5,ord) entries are added. But I don’t know how to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to calculate the power for each row based on the conditions you've mentioned. If I understand correctly, the power for a parent (ord = 0) is the sum of the powers of its children, and for children (ord > 0), the power is set to 0.

Your recursive CTE attempts to traverse the tree structure, but it seems like there's an issue with how the powers are calculated. Here's a revised version of your query:

```sql
with recursive Tree(id, p_id, power, ord, root_id) as (
    select id, p_id, power, ord, id as root_id
    from YourTableName
    where ord = 0

    union all

    select t.id, t.p_id,
           case when t.ord = 0 then t.power else tree.power end as power,
           t.ord,
           tree.root_id
    from YourTableName t
    inner join Tree
    on (t.p_id = tree.id and t.ord = 0) or (t.id = tree.root_id and t.ord > 0)
)
select id, p_id, sum(power) as calculated_power
from Tree
group by id, p_id
order by id;
```

This query uses the `union all` for recursive parts and includes a `sum(power)` in the final select to calculate the power for each parent based on the sum of its children's powers.

Please replace `YourTableName` with the actual name of your table. Additionally, make sure to test this on a small subset of your data before running it on the entire dataset to ensure it produces the expected results.

Comment: unfortunately, you are wrong. An entry with ord = 0 is a leaf node and only they have a known power value. and for the rest with ord > 0 power = the sum of power for records with p_id like our current record